# Is there any function to compute PRESS statistics in R?

Tags: r, statistics, lm

In one experiment we would like to compare two methods to estimate the plant coverage (e.g. method-A vs method-B). We used the [RMSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-mean-square_deviation) to explore the goodness of the correlation between both plant coverage estimation, and also the R2. A reviewer asked us if we could provide a [PRESS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PRESS_statistic) statistic.

Q1. Any suggestion to compute the PRESS statistics of a linear regression in R?
Q2. One step further ¿any way to implement in the [broom](https://broom.tidymodels.org/) package?

Thanks in advance
AntonioJ

Comment: `library("sos"); findFn("{press statistic}")` ...

Comment: Thanks @BenBolker, I didn't know this awesome `sos` package. It found several pkgs. Thanks

Comment: If you found a solution, you're encouraged to post an answer to your own question. (It would be interesting to add PRESS to the results of `broom::glance.lm()`, you could post that as a wish-list item at https://github.com/tidymodels/broom/issues